# Changing PATH during bitbake recipe do_compile_prepend

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

I'm trying to compile snort's daq in a bitbake recipe. As you can see [here (on line 45)](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/snort/doc/README.daq?rev=17490), I need to add to the path so that configure can find daq-modules-config. I did some searching, and I believe I have to add 
"${TMPDIR}/work/i486-angstrom-linux/daq-${PV}-${PR}/install/daq/usr/bin/" to my PATH before running configure.

Thus far I've tried a few variations on this:

```
MYBIN = "${TMPDIR}/work/i486-angstrom-linux/daq-${PV}-${PR}/install/daq/usr/bin/"

do_configure_prepend() {
    PATH=${MYBIN}:$PATH
}
```

without luck. Even if that sets the variable (which I'm not certain it's doing correctly) I suspect that it still wouldn't work... I'd need to set the variable as part of the same command that actually runs configure. However, there's no do_configure in the recipe - just `include autotools`.

I'm a complete bitbake, configure, and autotools newbie so I'm a little lost. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here at "6.5 Running a task" can provide you some info.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/poky-ref-manual/poky-ref-manual.html#ref-bitbake-tasklist

I have no access to bitbake right now, but maybe it works.

I would do:

in your local.conf:

```
export PATH
```

in recipe:

```
OLD_PATH=$PATH

do_setpath {
    export PATH=$PATH:<your_bin>
    export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="$BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE PATH"
}

do_resetpath {
    export PATH=$OLD_PATH
}

add task do_setpath before do_configure
add task do_resetpath after do_package
```