# How to add a directory to $PATH in a yocto recipe

Tags: path, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a Linux system which I create with Yocto.
In this I have two users: root, myuser

Now I want to change the variable `$PATH` of the two users so that the files under `/opt/myStuff/lib/` are found there.
I have already tried the following, but without success:

```
do_install(){
    install -d ${D}/opt/myStuff/lib/
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/myStuff/lib
}

FILES:${PN} += " \
    /opt/myStuff/lib/ \
"
```

This does not throw an error when building the image, but has no visible effect. I would imagine that this doesn't work because it is executed during the build process, and thus doesn't end up on the final image.
Also, I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750896/changing-path-during-bitbake-recipe-do-compile-prepend) question, but this seems to be too much outdated, as neither the code nor the source given there works.

So I wanted to ask what I have to do to make the path to my files end up in the `$PATH` variable of both users.
Is there perhaps a magic variable to set for this?

Regards

Comment: Depending on your shell, this would be something that you would add to some global environment variable section, like `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` directory, into scripts that are sourced/executed upon starting a shell.